# Selenium StaleElementReferenceException when page is reloading (FluentWait)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wrote the following function:

```
    public static IWebElement FluentWait(By locator) {
        var fluentWait = new DefaultWait<IWebDriver>(WebDriver.GetDriver)
        {
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), 
            PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5)
        };

        fluentWait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException), 
            typeof(StaleElementReferenceException), 
            typeof(ElementNotInteractableException), 
            typeof(ElementClickInterceptedException));

        fluentWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(locator));

        return fluentWait.Until(x=> x.FindElement(locator));
    }
```

With this function I can do something like:

`FluentWait(By.Id("myId")).Click();`

The problem, however, is that my `FluentWait()` function fails, because Selenium is too fast and starts checking for:

`fluentWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(locator));` even before the page starts even reloading, so it always finds the old non-stale element and the `Until()` becomes true.

Page reload is executed by clicking on a button that sends PATCH request and reloads the page, that button is clicked before, I try to click on:

`FluentWait(By.Id("myId")).Click();`

Also, something like the code below won't work for the same reason as above.

`wait.Until(driver=>((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));`

The only solution I can think of right now is to make use of `Thread.Sleep(n)`, but I rather avoid this, can someone help me find a better solution.

Comment: first wait for element that indicates that the page has loaded?

Comment: I can't do that because it's button on the website that actually refreshes the page, also `FluentWait(By.Id("myId")).Click();` happens after that button (which refreshes the page) was clicked.

Comment: use explicit wait, rather than fluent wait, and use it to check for any element that you know is visible after page is refresged

Comment: @AdrianJimenez there is no way for me to check that page is refreshing, because my code doesn't really wait till page starts refreshing, if I check for refresh it would happen before the refresh happens, so the code will think that the page is ready (already refreshed),  this is the problem I am facing.